# Where do I put my clear fix to clear the float?

Tags: html

I want to use clear-fix to clear the float on my nav, so the container's height will be the height of its child element. But I am not sure where to put my clear-fix.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container">

            <nav id="nav">
                <a href="#principle_1">1</a>
                <a href="#principle_2">2</a>
                <a href="#principle_3">3</a>
                <a href="#principle_4">4</a>
                <a href="#principle_5">5</a>
                <a href="#principle_6">6</a>
                <a href="#principle_7">7</a>
                <a href="#principle_8">8</a>
                <a href="#principle_9">9</a>
                <a href="#principle_10">10</a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </nav>

      </div>
```

I find that when I put the clear-fix in the nav, it clear the float of nav's child elements. When I put it outside of nav, but in the container, it also works.(see code below)Since both two position works, I am not sure what's the difference between this two positions.

```
<div class="container">

            <nav id="nav">
                <a href="#principle_1">1</a>
                <a href="#principle_2">2</a>
                <a href="#principle_3">3</a>
                <a href="#principle_4">4</a>
                <a href="#principle_5">5</a>
                <a href="#principle_6">6</a>
                <a href="#principle_7">7</a>
                <a href="#principle_8">8</a>
                <a href="#principle_9">9</a>
                <a href="#principle_10">10</a>

          </nav>
          <div class="clear"></div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an element contains only floated elements, its height collapses to nothing. That's why the container doesn't have a height without a clearfix. If you want the container to always be able to resize, so that it contains floating elements inside it, you need to self-clear its children. So the container will regain height. One way to do it is to use a clearfix.

```
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    .clearfix {
      clear: both;
    }
```

The clearfix will clear the float on its children. So in your code, if you put the clearfix indise the `#nav`, it will clear the float of all the `a` tags. So the `nav` will has height. So the `container` will has height, too. In the below example, both nav and container has heights, so they both have background color.

```css
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  background: pink;
}

#nav {
  background: blue;
}

#nav a {
    width: 97.8px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: 'robotomedium';
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <nav id="nav">
                <a href="#principle_1">1</a>
                <a href="#principle_2">2</a>
                <a href="#principle_3">3</a>
                <a href="#principle_4">4</a>
                <a href="#principle_5">5</a>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </nav>
</div>
```

If you insert the `clearfix` inside the `container`, it will clear the float on the `a` tags, too. But the `#nav` will collapse, because you do not clear the float inside it. So in the browser, the `a` tag becomes the direct children of `container`.  In the below ex., the `#nav` doesn't has height, but the `container` does.

```css
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
   background: pink;
}

#nav {
  background: blue;
}


#nav a {
    width: 97.8px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: 'robotomedium';
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <nav id="nav">
                <a href="#principle_1">1</a>
                <a href="#principle_2">2</a>
                <a href="#principle_3">3</a>
                <a href="#principle_4">4</a>
                <a href="#principle_5">5</a>
            </nav>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**So the key is clearing an element's children to prevent collapse for that element.**

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the nav element so that it is a child of the clearfix.

The hierarchy should look like this: `div.container > div.clear > nav`

Comment: Thank you! I tried your structure, but the container's height is 0. It seems the clearfix does not clear the float of the child element.